# "Namespace name 'React' could not be found" after adding reactjs.net to Orchard theme

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9, reactjs.net

I have a web site built with Orchard, including a custom theme.

I added ReactJS.net to the theme via NuGet. It compiles fine, but when I try to render a view, I get the following error:

`CS0246: The type or namespace name 'React' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

React.Core, React.Web and React.Web.Mvc4 all appear in the project's References.

I'm at a loss as to why the view isn't finding React. Do I also need to include ReactJS.net in other Orchard projects for some reason?

Comment: You may need to set CopyLocal=true or add it to your web.config. Maybe the nuget setup didn't work correctly.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet, where you are trying to render the script?

Comment: @KevBelisle, did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @FibreChips No, I abandonned ReactJS.net in favor of using npm and webpack directly to compile my JSX.